# Cache filter on collection with Guava

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I'm developing a program that performs some operations on automatas. An automata is made up of states (aka node) and transitions (aka edges) and I need to filter them to retrieve set with particular properties. This operation is easy to implement, but it is performed several times and I would write a little cache on it.

In the fragment of code below there is my implementation and **I'd like to know if is the correct way to filter and memoize the observable transitions**.

```
public class Automata {
    private State initial;
    private Set <State> states; 
    private Set <Transition> transitions;
    private Supplier <Set <Transition>> observables;

    // ...

    public Automata() {
        this.initial = new State();
        this.states = new HashSet <> ();
        this.transitions = new HashSet <> ();

        this.observables = Suppliers.memoize(() ->
           transitions.stream().filter((t) -> 
              (t.isObservable() == true)).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }

    public getObservables() {
         return observables.get();
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it correct?
2. If a transition changes its observability is this information propagate also to the Supplier?

I'm sorry for my poor English, i hope that is enough clear.

Comment: I don't get a question. Can you please specify it more explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it's correct.
2. No, changes you will do in transitions won't automatically be propagated. And for this case Supplier AFAIK not suitable.
   Either you need to overwrite it manually like here:

   ```
   public void invalidate(){
       memorized = Suppliers.memoize(supplier);
   }
   ```

   Also `memoizeWithExpiration` will work if you know that your update will be not so frequent and you don't need reliable reads.

   Or you just need to use `Cache`, for example:

   ```
   CacheLoader<Key, Graph> loader = new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
     public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
       return createExpensiveGraph(key);
     }
   };
   LoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(loader);
   ```

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable but can you explain me better how to adapt a `CacheLoader` on my problem?